# Slide Elements in Different Directions left/right/bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, slide

Trying to Slide `h3` to left direction, `p` to right direction and `.info` bottom to Top direction on this [slider](http://slycore-demo.blogspot.com). Actually it working perfectly in *Chrome and Opera* without jQuery, because I have used Animate.css, but it's not working in *Mozila firefox 35.0.1+* . So I have to do it by jQuery for firefox.

*HTML:*

```
<div id="headslide">
<ul>
<li class="post-content">
<div class="slidshow-thumbnail">
<a href="#">
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-h4-nQvZ5-VE/VQ3HLtSS3ZI/AAAAAAAABIc/iaOda5zoUMw/s350-h260-c/girl_with_winter_hat-wallpaper-1024x768.jpg" height="260" width="350"/>
</a>
</div>
<span class="content-margin">
<p>Cicero famously orated against his p...</p>
<h3><a href="#">Download Premium Blogger Templates</a></h3>
<span class="info">Info</span>
</span>
</li>
<li class="post-content">
<div class="slidshow-thumbnail">
<a href="#">
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-YfkF1u_VB40/VWr5dYf00gI/AAAAAAAABW8/wv2e-Lu4etw/s390-h340-c-h340-c/11071467_807062866056131_872486685669967339_n.jpg" height="260" width="350"/>
</a>
</div>
<span class="content-margin">
<p>SEO friendly Flat style Custom Fonts.</p>
<h3><a href="#">Modern with a pixel-perfect eye</a></h3>
<span class="info">Info</span>
</span>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="pager"></div>
</div>
```

Want to implement three type effects `slideLeft` for `h3`, `slideRight` for  `p`(description) and slide *bottom to top* for `.info`. On Chrome it's working perfectly but not working on Mozila firefox. This Slider has fade transition by default, so it show fade transition on firefox and my bounceInLeft/bounceInRight keyframes works only on Chrome, Opera.

My question is how to do this by jQuery:

Please See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bacec898/) >> on latest Chrome and Mozila Firefox 35.0.1+.
Thanks.

Comment: To test if this is a prefixing issue, I'd suggest adding [prefix-free](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/prefixfree) and see if the issue persists

Comment: @Professor.CSS thanks, i have tested, still not work. any other suggestion? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bacec898/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
For the right slide effect use this.

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").animate({right: "+=100px"});
});
$(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").animate({right: "0"});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button class="btn1">Animate</button>
<button class="btn2">Reset</button>

<p style="position:absolute;right:0;">This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>

You can check here at W3Schools for different jquery effects.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp
```